Get MongoDB Stream Real Time data in the front facing
I am trying to get the my MongoDB Atlas changes updated in real time in the front user facing. I am trying to implement the Mongo Change Stream functions. I am able to get the changes in my file but not sure how I will pass those changes to the front-end page.
Inside my Mongodb Stream file I am already getting the changes from MongoDB, all changes are being showing on that "change" inside the "for while". I just need to know how I can pass that to the front facing part. If someone could help me on that, I tried some stuff but nothing worked there.
I am working with 3 files -
The Main front facing file code -
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { columns } from './columns';
import { DataTable } from './DataTable';

export default function JobsTable() {
  const [sseConnection, setSSEConnection] = useState(null);
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/jobs');
      setJobs(response.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const listenToSSEUpdates = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('listenToSSEUpdates func');
    const eventSource = new EventSource('/api/sse');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    listenToSSEUpdates();

    return () => {
      if (sseConnection) {
        sseConnection.close();
      }
    };
  }, [listenToSSEUpdates]);

  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      <DataTable columns={columns} data={jobs} />{' '}
    </div>
  );
}

My API SSE File:
import { changeStream } from '@/lib/mongoChangeStream';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';


const HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 seconds (adjust this as needed)


export async function GET(req, res) {
  // Check if the client accepts SSE
  const headersList = headers();
  const accept = headersList.get('accept');


  return new NextResponse('ok');
}

My MongoDB Stream Connection:
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';


const uri = process.env.DATABASE_URL || '';
const client = new MongoClient(uri);


export let changeStream;


async function run() {
  try {
    console.log('Setting up change stream');
    const database = client.db('pcb');
    const collection = database.collection('Jobs');


    const options = { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' };
    // This could be any pipeline.
    const pipeline = [];


    // Open a Change Stream on the "jobs" collection
    changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline, options);


    // Print change events as they occur


    for await (const change of changeStream) {
      console.log('Received change:\n', change);
    }


    // Close the change stream when done
    await changeStream.close();
  } finally {
    // Close the MongoDB client connection


    await client.close();
  }
}


run().catch(console.dir);


Search for "nextjs websockets" there are a lot of tutorials and projects on github.
